# How can I copy a file from an Android phone to a connected USB drive?

Tags: files

I have a USB harddrive connected to my Android 10 phone via USB C. How can I copy files from to phone to it?

When I go into the "Files" app, select a file and hit "Copy to...", it doesn't give me a choice of destination, it just sends it to the SD card. I can see the drive in the app and even create new folders in it and see its contents, I just can't copy anything to it. I've already tapped the "allow access to this drive" thing in the app.

Answer (score 0):

Disconnecting and reconnecting the drive fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Another suggestion: upgrade your file app experience.  [MixPlorer](http://mixplorer.com/) is my recommendation.  Allows file connection from phone to everything, including cloud drives, local network, and all the folders on the phone (including system folders).